# Doctrine join bypass lazy loading

Tags: join, orm, symfony, doctrine

I just started exploring Symfony2 and I am amazed how many great features it has. I started doing the blog tutorial at:
http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/
but using version 2.1 instead of 2.0

My problem is that i have the following entity for Blog:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="blog")
 */
protected $comments;
```

and the following in the Comment entity:

```
/**
 * @var string $blog
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Blog", inversedBy="comments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="blog_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $blog;
```

I created the function to get the latest blogs and join the comments so i dont have to lazy load comments for each blog and avoid multiple calls to the comments table like so:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
            ->select('b')
            ->leftJoin('b.comments', 'c')
            ->addOrderBy('b.created', 'DESC');
```

but when i run in the twig template the result from that query as: `blog.comments`  I got the first query to retrieve the blogs correct with the join in it but then instead of using the joined value for comments i get a call to the comments table for each blog entry? How do I bypass that functionality for that certain case but keep the relationship so i can get all comments for a blog from the view blog page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You also need to add the comment objects to the select results:

```
->select('b', 'c')
```

Comment: when I do this I have only one single result... Do you know why?

Comment: Do you get them correctly without this modification? Does the generated query seem ok? (You can check this in the profiler.)

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Yes, I get everything correctly with lazy loading (but it requires many query). That is my DQL query: 

`$dql = "SELECT u, fb FROM SportBundle:Project u LEFT JOIN u.feedbacks fb WHERE u.id = :project_id ORDER BY fb.creation_date ASC";`

Comment: @benske probably you're using a limit with setMaxResults() or something. Using this method the limit is applied to the total number of rows. So each row contains a blog and a comment, the blog fields being repeated for each comment on the blog. So if the first blog has many comments and you are using a small limit you'll just get the one blog with comments up to the limit. You can avoid this by using two queries, The first gets just the blog ids with a limit. The second gets the blogs and the comments with the blog ids.

Comment: @DavidStone the setMaxResults approach may be correct, but the proper way to solve that is by using a Doctrine Paginator. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html